# PYTHON: requests and response 401

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a little problem with authentication. I am writting a script, which is getting login and password from user(input from keyboard) and then I want to get some data from the website(http not https), but every time I run the script the response is  401.I read some similar posts from stack and I tried this solutions:

Solution 1

```
c = HTTPConnection("somewebsite")
userAndPass = b64encode(b"username:password").decode("ascii")
headers = { 'Authorization' : 'Basic %s' %  userAndPass }
c.request('GET', '/', headers=headers)
res = c.getresponse()
data = res.read()
```

Solution 2

```
with requests.Session() as c:
    url = 'somewebsite'
    USERNAME = 'username'
    PASSWORD = 'password'
    c.get(url)
    login_data = dict(username = USERNAME, password = PASSWORD)
    c.post(url,data = login_data)
    page = c.get('somewebsite', headers = {"Referer": "somwebsite"})
    print(page)
```

Solution 3

```
www = 'somewebsite'
value ={'filter':'somefilter'}
data = urllib.parse.urlencode(value)
data=data.encode('utf-8')
req = urllib.request.Request(www,data)
resp = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
respData = resp.read()
print(respData)
x = urllib.request.urlopen(www,"username","password")
print(x.read())'
```

I don't know how to solve this problem. Can somebody give me some link or tip ?

Comment: maybe your username or password is incorrect because it may be reading the error code 401 which means HTTP 401 Unauthorized client error status response code so you may be unauthorized to login

Comment: When I open the website thought the browser and I write my password and login it`s ok, but when I run this from cmd I get 401

Comment: Trace the requests in the browser's developer tools to find out what it's doing. If none of the basic authentication examples are working, it must be something else.

Comment: @MB_YD hey did you get this working? I landed in the same situation.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried the [Basic Authentication](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/authentication/#basic-authentication) example from requests?

```
>>> from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
>>> requests.get('https://api.github.com/user', auth=HTTPBasicAuth('user', 'pass'))
<Response [200]>
```

Comment: Yes, but 401 :(

Answer (score 2):

Can I know what type of authentication on the website?

this is an official Basic Auth example (http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#http-verbs)

```
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
auth = HTTPBasicAuth('fake@example.com', 'not_a_real_password')

r = requests.post(url=url, data=body, auth=auth)
print(r.status_code)
```

Comment: I checked it and it is : NTLM

Comment: Can you use chrome developer tools?? it provides you to trace Request Headers. This may help: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network-performance/reference#headers

Answer (score 1):

To use api with authentication, we need to have token_id or app_id that will provide the access for our request. Below is an example how we can formulate the url and get the response:
**strong text**

```
import requests
city = input()
api_call = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?"
app_id = "892d5406f4811786e2b80a823c78f466"
req_url = api_call + "q=" + city + "&appid=" + app_id
response = requests.get(req_url)
data = response.json()
if (data["cod"] == 200):
    hum = data["main"]["humidity"]
    print("Humidity is % d " %(hum))
elif data["cod"] != 200:
    print("Error occurred : " ,data["cod"], data["message"])
```