# GCP Python SDK - Get data from the googleapi url's

Tags: python, json, google-cloud-platform, sdk

How do we work on the URLs in the JSON output below?

Python SDK command for subnetworks:

```
"request = service.subnetworks().list(project=project, region=reg['name'])"
```

JSON output below:

```
{'creationTimestamp': '2022-02-15T09:35:32.833-08:00',
 'enableFlowLogs': True,
 'fingerprint': '',
 'gatewayAddress': '',
 'id': '',
 'ipCidrRange': '',
 'kind': 'compute#subnetwork',
 'logConfig': {'aggregationInterval': 'INTERVAL_5_SEC',
               'enable': True,
               'filterExpr': 'true',
               'flowSampling': 0.5,
               'metadata': 'INCLUDE_ALL_METADATA'},
 'name': '',
 ***'network': 'https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/{}/global/networks/{}',***
 'privateIpGoogleAccess': True,
 'privateIpv6GoogleAccess': 'DISABLE_GOOGLE_ACCESS',
 'purpose': 'PRIVATE',
 ***'region': 'https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/{}/regions/{}',***
 ***'selfLink': 'https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/{}/regions/{}/subnetworks/{}***',
 'stackType': 'IPV4_ONLY'}
```

Is there a way I can get the data from the URLs using python?

```
 'network': 'https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/{}/global/networks/{}',
 'region': 'https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/{}/regions/{}',
 'selfLink': 'https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/{}/regions/{}/subnetworks/{}',
```

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. Rewrite your question into a software programming problem. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please let me know if there are queries still...

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```py
import json
import requests

with open("data.json", "r") as f:
  data = json.load(f)

network_url = data["network"]

network_data = requests.get(network_url)

# For instance, write data to text file.
with open("network_data.txt", "w") as file:
    file.write(network_data.text)
```

Comment: I can retrieve data from JSON, is there a way in python to retrieve data contained in those URLs?

Comment: Thank you.... When i run the code i get the error: <Response [401]> Authentication error

Comment: Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51925956/python-requests-and-response-401). The error is clear, you an authentication  issue. What happen when you type `from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth` and then `requests.get('https://api.github.com/user', auth=HTTPBasicAuth('user', 'pass'))` ?

Comment: The URLs in the JSON are not real URLs. They are a naming convention. You cannot make an HTTP request using those values (in most cases).

Comment: Thank you blunova !
I was able to make an API call in Python using those URLs. That's how i was able to get the data from it.